# Xamarin.Forms Shell: Passing objects from one vm to another

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I see how to pass data in the form of strings  [from one object to another](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shell-query-parameters/)

What I want to do, however, is pass an object from one vm to another -- is this possible? I can think of these ideas:

1. Stream the object as json and pass that as a param.
2. Use an id to look up and create the object
   in the receiving vm
3. Pass the object itself (ideal)

Will any of these work (well, #2 almost certainly will)?  If 1 or 3 will work, can you possibly supply (detailed?) instructions on how to do so?

Thanks!!
jesse liberty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the following at the top of the page that will be **receiving** the data

   ```
    [QueryProperty(nameof(CodesToAdd), nameof(CodesToAdd))]
   ```
2. Create a corresponding property (in this case CodesToAdd)
3. In the setter for that property getg the string value passed to you

   _codesToAdd = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value ?? string.Empty);

To **send** the data (in this case the codes to add) put this in the calling program:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(AddWidgetPage)}?CodesToAdd={codesToAddAsString}");
```

The first part in the parens identifies the page you want to navigate to. The part after the ? is the parameter. Make sure your param name (CodesToAdd) matches the one in your receiving page.

Answer (score 0):

Add an parameter in your page constructor like:

```
 public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
public MyPage(Object sth)
{..... }}
```

Then pass the object with

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(sth));
```